# React Navigation: multiple nested navigators - Stack -> Tab Nav -> Tab Nav/Router(can't decide) -> stack

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

Edit April 2019: simpler is always better, I ended up rolling a non-navigation related solution for what I was trying to accomplish. Whatever was broken here was undoubtedly something I was doing wrong.

Because I'm a masochist, the first time I'm using react native I am attempting to build a relatively complex social media app (note this is my first time so consequently I may be doing this completely wrong) that has the format as follows (pseudocode):

```
Stack Navigator: 
    Home: BottomTabNavigator
    CreatePostScreen: CreatePostScreen
    CreatePostScreen2: CreatePostScreen2, etc
```

(I have the "create post screens" at the highest level of the stack so that when you load that page, it doesn't show the tab bar for obvious reasons)

```
BottomTabNavigator = TabNavigator:
    Homescreen: HomeTabRouter (TabRouter, see below)
    Explore: ExploreNavigator (stack navigator, works fine)
    Notifications: NotificationsNavigator (stack navigator, works fine)
    Profile: ProfileNavigator (stack navigator, works fine)
```

Here's where it starts to get complex (this is actual code, and I'll explain why I can't decide between tab navigator and tab router after)

```
export const HomeTabNavigator = TabRouter({
    FriendsNavigator: {
        screen: FriendsNavigator,
        path: 'Friends',
        routeName: 'Friends',
    },
    LocalNavigator: {
        screen: LocalNavigator,       
        path: 'LocalScreen',
        routeName: 'LocalScreen'
    },

}, 
{
    headerMode: 'none',
}
)

const CustomTabView = ({ router, navigation }) => {
    const { routes, index } = navigation.state;
    const ActiveScreen = router.getComponentForRouteName(routes[index].routeName);   
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <ActiveScreen
            // navigation={navigation} (commented out because if it's not, 
            my app won't render anything and tell me there is no route defined
            for key "LocalNavigator" and this is because the ActiveScreen
            is a StackNavigator that isn't aware of the other StackNavigators
            even though I think it should be???)
        />
        </View>
    );
};

export default HomeTabRouter = createNavigationContainer(
    createNavigator(HomeTabNavigator)(CustomTabView)
)
```

(this code comes before instantiation of HomeTabNavigator but for readability's sake I'm putting it after)

```
export const FriendsNavigator = StackNavigator({
    FriendPostsScreen: {
        screen: FriendPostsScreen,
        path: 'Friends',
        routeName: 'Friends'
    },
    IndividualFriendPostPage: {
        screen: IndividualFriendPostPage,
        routeName: 'IndividualFriendPostPage'        
    }
},    
{
    headerMode: 'none',

});
(LocalNavigator is an exact copy of FriendsNavigator, just gives the option to 
navigate between the screen of all posts and the screen of a specific post)
```

The issue I'm having with the tab router is that the code as it is either

A. if navigation={navigation} for ActiveScreen is commented out, I can't navigate from the FriendPostsScreen to the LocalPostsScreen from a button declared on FriendPostsScreen even if I connect the class to the global navigation and navigate to the routename declared in that index (I'm aware I can construct the navigation buttons elsewhere, but until I changed HomeTabNavigator from being FriendsScreen to FriendsNavigator rendering the buttons in a SafeAreaView on the FriendsScreen worked fine) [screenshot when commented out.](https://prnt.sc/hpturk) And, interestingly enough, if I turn HomeTabRouter into a Tab Navigator, clicking the same buttons will navigate me to the page I clicked.

B. if it's not commented out, it tells me "there is no key defined for route LocalNavigator" [screenshot](https://prnt.sc/hptuj2)

I know that it's not an issue with the actual key/routename because I've tested it and passed every possible routename.

I can't set the screen of "Homescreen" in the BottomTabNavigator to the non navigationContainer HomeTabNavigator because it tells me "I must declare a screen," and I don't know of any other way to use a tab router.

Before I list my reasoning on using a tab navigator, I want to reiterate that the tab router setup with CustomTabView worked fine until I nested stacknavigators in it.

BottomTabNavigator is obviously, already a Tab Navigator and I haven't figured out a way to only set navigationOptions: { tabBarVisible: false } for the nested tab navigator, not both, because I need to be able to customize the tab navigator bar of Friends/Local to include a button that links me to the CreatePostScreen a level above the original BottomTabNavigator. [screenshot](http://prntscr.com/hpty4w)

I've done a decent amount of research and I'm pretty certain that the issue is one of two things: 
1. I don't fully understand how stack navigators work and I'm doing something wrong that makes it incompatible with TabRouter 
2. There is an inherent issue with nesting StackNavigators in a TabRouter.

Regardless of the issue, like I said in the beginning, I'm new to react native and react-navigation. Based on what I'm trying to accomplish with the nested navigators, am I going about it the right way? What do you recommend?

I know it's long but I just didn't want to skip any details, so thanks for taking the time to read!